What is the usage of Timeout setting of the Azure Function activity inside the Azure Data Factory?

I tried from 10 min to 7 days on the Timeout setting. It always returns timeout error after 230 seconds.
I have read the documentation citing the 230 second timeout limitation.
I would like to know what is thus the usage of this Timeout setting when it actually times out after 230 seconds?

Azure Functions times out after 230 seconds regardless of the functionTimeout setting you've configured, refer MSDOC.

Consider durable functions or move to a premium function plan which allows for higher timeouts in the function

@KerNIM, check if below solution helps.

The ADF Timeout setting is used to allow ADF to wait for specified time period before considering the activity a failure. It does not override the function app's execution timeout.
This setting is configured to make sure ADF doesn't wait indefinitely for the function which may take too long to execute.
If the function execution exceeds the defined ADF timeout, the pipeline activity will be failed even if the function continues running in the background.
Azure Functions have their own timeout configuration, which can be managed by setting functionTimeout in host.json.
Function app timeout for specific plans:

Regardless of the defined function app timeout setting, Azure Function will timeout once the execution time reaches 230 seconds.
This is due to underlying infrastructure that Azure Functions use such as Azure Load Balancer which has a default idle timeout setting of 4 minutes(response time limit for a web request).

App Service returns a timeout to the client if your application does not return a response within approximately 240 seconds (230 seconds on Windows app, 240 seconds on Linux app) as mentioned in MSDOC.

If your Azure function requires longer time for its execution i.e., more than 230 seconds, use Durable Functions.
Durable Functions run asynchronously and support longer running tasks without any timeouts.
I have created a durable Azure function and configured with Azure Data factory:

Output:
Durable functions creates background process and gives a few URLs to interact with the process including one URL to query its status, refer SO answer by @UtkarshPal.
 {
    "id": "badb8e26563c47459511f7baf6a291e3",
    "purgeHistoryDeleteUri": " https://kpfn11.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/badb8e26563c47459511f7baf6a291e3?code=k2T5xoJWvVgyRXXXBtanotcFAzFuvIpYug== ",
    "sendEventPostUri": " https://kpfn11.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/badb8e26563XXXa291e3/raiseEvent/ {eventName}?code=k2T5xoJWvVgyRjLXXXBtanotcFAzFuvIpYug==",
    "statusQueryGetUri": " https://kpfn11.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/badbXXXbaf6a291e3?code=k2T5xoJWvVgyRjLxlyBvlWw1cMXXXuvIpYug== ",
    "terminatePostUri": " https://kpfn11.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/badb8e265XXX1f7baf6a291e3/terminate?reason= {{text}}&code=k2T5xoJWvVgyRjLxXXcMmpu0oyVjhFBtanotcFAzFuvIpYug==",
    "suspendPostUri": " https://kpfn11.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/badbXX11f7baf6a291e3/suspend?reason= {{text}}&code=k2T5xoJWvVgyRjXXpu0oyVjhFBtanotcFAzFuvIpYug==",
    "resumePostUri": " https://kpfn11.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/badb8eXX7baf6a291e3/resume?reason= {{text}}&code=k2T5xoJWvVgyRXXMmpu0oyVjhFBtanotcFAzFuvIpYug==",
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (East US)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
} 

